# How can I cast or change the generic type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
function cast<R, T>(v: T): R {
  return v as R;
         ~~~~~~
         // Error
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is to change the type of `v` from T to R. But, I see the error following.

```
Conversion of type 'T' to type 'R' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  'T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

And using `InstanceType<typeof R>` also gives me an error.
Is there somebody who knows how to do this?

Comment: "If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first" `v as unknown as R`

Comment: You know that "`cast`" is unsafe, though, right?  You're using the word "cast" but all TypeScript has is [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) which have no runtime effect.  What is the use case for this `cast` function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TypeScript's [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), of the form `expr as Type`, allow you to tell the compiler that an expression `expr` is of a particular type `Type`.  The compiler usually does a pretty good job figuring out what types expressions should be, but sometimes you the developer know something that the compiler doesn't, and this is how you tell the compiler.

Note that `expr as Type` *does not* have any runtime effect whatsoever.  For the most part, the types that appear in TypeScript merely *describe* what is expected to happen at runtime; they do not *change* what happens.  The static type system is essentially [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the JavaScript that actually runs.

So, `expr as number` is a compile time *type assertion*, [not a runtime *type cast*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-this-incorrect-cast-throw-a-runtime-error). It does not, for example, perform [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) like `0+expr` or [type conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_conversion) like `Number(expr)`.

---

Okay, a type assertion lets us tell the compiler what type it should consider the expression to be.  But the compiler does not automatically accept all such assertions without complaint.  Generally, it will allow the assertion if it already thinks the expression is assignable to that type:

```
const foo = "foo" as string; // okay, widened from "foo" to string
```

which you can think of as "upcasting" but which might be better described as "widening".  It will also allow the assertion if it thinks the expression *might be* that type, because the asserted type is assignable to it:

```
let bar = (Math.random() < 99 ? "bar" : 1) as string; 
// okay, narrowed from string | number to string
```

which you can think of as "downcasting" but which might be better described as "narrowing".  These rules aren't the whole story, but the general idea is that the compiler will allow assertions if they are widening or narrowing.

---

The compiler balks at an assertion it thinks of as neither widening nor narrowing.  If it thinks you are taking an expression of type `X` and asserting that it is of type `Y`, and if neither `X` nor `Y` are assignable to the other, then the types don't "sufficiently overlap" each other and you might be doing the type assertion in error.  This is the case with the two unspecified generic type parameters `T` and `R`.  If `T extends R` or `R extends T` were true, that would be fine, but as it stands they could be completely unrelated types, so the assertion is blocked:

```
function castBad<R, T>(v: T): R {
    return v as R; // error!
    // --> ~~~~~~
    // Conversion of type 'T' to type 'R' may be a mistake because 
    // neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.
    // If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
}
```

The error message gives you the hint you need to make this succeed: do an intermediate type assertion to something either so wide or so narrow that the compiler sees each step as related.  All types are assignable to the [`unknown` type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type), so you can use it as an intermediate:

```
function cast<R, T>(v: T): R {
    return v as unknown as R; // okay
}
```

With `v as unknown` you are widening `T` to `unknown`, and then with `(v as unknown) as R` you are narrowing `unknown` to `R`.  You could also use any of the following:

```
v as never as R; // narrow to never, widen back to R
v as any as R; // narrow/widen to any, narrow/widen back to R
v as (T | R) as R; // widen to the union, narrow back to the other member
v as (T & R) as R; // narrow to the intersection, widen back to the other member
```

---

So, that should work.  I'm concerned about the use case for a function like `cast()`, since it is just a type assertion dressed up as a function, and therefore has the same caveats about not really being what people usually mean by "cast":

```
const x = cast<number, string>("hello");
console.log(x.toFixed(1)); // okay at compile time, error at runtime.  oops
```

Furthermore, if you really do want to have a type assertion function, the `T` generic parameter isn't doing much heavy lifting; it has to be specified manually but could reasonably be inferred by the argument you pass in.  And in fact, since it's only used for the type of the argument, you could just eliminate it entirely:

```
function typeAssert<R>(v: any): R {
    return v;
}
```

And then when you use it you only need to specify the desired return type:

```
const y = typeAssert<string>(Math.random() < 99 ? "okay" : 123); // string
```

---

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKFGMHsDsGcBcAEAzSlEF5ECJWW4gIayIIBOAltAOYDciA9A4pANaECeoANgKZIAjQmUyIAFAFlC8ABYA6MoWgATSAFsxASkQAeRAE59iAPw4hZAgC5EARm3FS8SjXpMW7LmBDIArtHDwFDCI4MTwAEKEyjoASgA0iAAqAHxiAG7WiZrWMYgA3qCIRYhk-D5k0IhpRCQxrsy8ZGSQZACEhcVuALRdyYgAfoNDHUVuAMIwaY2wQZWQyIjwHAAOvIgA5Inri+hLqxsx22qciAJrhIhqFAiErGtnoT6wayOMzNC8FLKNiytrsD5kMgKOAKLxoPBuBwWFMyNxCMsSAB3L4yRYyNaQb5kOSvNwASQWsmuiCRDio8HBgRghG4CSg0FhSG+iF4AA9lqVYDNgvB0Os-KxoJAkdBtsCyAhcSAAL6gUC+fzUyqhBCxBIpdKZbKIXIFEDFEplCpVGqIQXC0VmuqgOVeRUBWaLXhq+JJVIZJLafWG6oOC0iyoOG0G4p+kgfWHW2ivcNEaDQ4P0WNmsSJRAAH119lqMdDRTjacQADJs9HbfKvAyEIg2aJVfAdNAfGozmQEuQqNRUtgMdxuPhNHnq5A+HIB9QxGy5HyAGIUNm8ZRiOxDt7uE7SELqZYUPiLChqXgJRrNERbsh+QJHuRFNCIysO5W-VYAQW5jUbMQ91iUHB1eqvKU8DlJUaR5na1ZINCWB7Lw77PGQjadjQqRSLIChKKoGjaHohgmDgbCcFYtgAEwAMxDkAA)