# Why does a conditional type as return value require type assertions?

Tags: typescript

I created a function which accepts either `string | number | boolean | null` as parameter value but only returns either `string | boolean | "no_value"` depending on the type of the  parameter value in TypeScript. Here my code:

```
type OutputValue<T extends Value> = T extends string | number
    ? string : T extends boolean
    ? boolean
    : "no_value";

const getString = (val: number | string) => val.toString();

const myFunction = <T extends Value>(
    parameter: T
): OutputValue<T> => {
  if (typeof parameter === 'boolean') {
      return parameter; // ❌ Error: Type 'T & true' is not comparable to type 'OutputValue<T>'
  }
  if (typeof parameter === 'string' || typeof parameter === 'number') {
    return getString(parameter); // ❌ Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'OutputValue<T>'
  }
  return "no_value"; // ❌ Error: Type '"no_value"' is not assignable to type 'OutputValue<T>'
}

myFunction("3");
```

As you can see the three lines with return values contain errors. Adding type assertions `as OutputValue<T>` to the return values fixes two of the TS errors, but in the `boolean` case the error remains:

```
if (typeof parameter === 'boolean') {
    return parameter as OutputValue<T>; // ❌ Error: Type 'T & true' is not comparable to type 'OutputValue<T>'
}
```

Here one can follow the advice in the error message *"If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first."* to get rid of the compile error:

```
if (typeof parameter === 'boolean') {
    return parameter as unknown as OutputValue<T>; // ✅ no error
}
```

I don't get why TypeScript wants me to add type assertions in the first place! I think I shouldn't need them because I implement the function exactly as I define my type `OutputValue` and link the parameter value to the return value via a generic type `T`. I also don't understand why TypeScript believes that the return value in the `boolean` case is supposed to have the type `T & true`? No idea where the `true` comes from..

---

As part of my investigation into the issue I got even more confused about the whole thing! When simplifying the conditional type `OutputValue` a little bit, the requirement to convert the expression to 'unknown' first disappears and the following code has no error:

```
type OutputValue<T extends Value> = T extends boolean
    ? boolean
    : "no_value";

const myFunction = <T extends Value>(
    parameter: T
): OutputValue<T> => {
  if (typeof parameter === 'boolean') {
      return parameter as OutputValue<T>; // ✅ no error
  }
  return "no_value" as OutputValue<T>;
}

myFunction(3);
```

What is going on here?

---

[TypeScript Playground with all examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQM7AE4EsB2A5lAD5T5IC2ARhNqVNQPZMIRz4MUIIDcAsACgh%20OJQgYwcAMbQAyrkpg2AdVzAAFgFFs2JtgxQA3kKhRQkKAHkkwMLfjIIAHgAqUCAA9gEfABNDRxQAPih0dy8ff0NmVnZ8UzMkgH5GFjYORKSoAC4oACJ8JgB9ADdEFHyBYUEzaSZ8LChKEAAxJHxpYFwGsKg3D29fANgKiGCACiykqWwxCB9sPNdEgEo8mzsHMbdQ1FCTWqTcADMoCYsIJjPZ%20cWw1HQAcliM-CfV42ns7AWkbE4t3Ei14UAA9GCoDo9EsoK5wNAnu4AGRQE6IDAQJ5QXCGIrAKBwDAYXCEUTUNjmJjmBFQJ6bezAIIuVzBJ7TAC%2001%20wH%20nEKJXKTiq4Mh0P0y1pTwFZTG%20WxuPITAJRJJZLgFOgwGplzpDO2Tl27KOXJqZha7U63QaEwAzKtqqaRPNJDJ5IplBA1JomLZxQYvkddfqmTsIkNoqMnHs4YMoiNXvFvlBUonMkdsnkZULKtVEvVGgSLR0uj1OOgBpFhoExpNk0CFnRlmsNrZGczdmEDtNTudLtcoA37o9nmn3p9Dtkfn8AYO4HNgXRCYYQx3WdVsqbp7zZ9m5cvrG2DShdhuoE6jsWrWW7Q6hBfROJXbIoABhJhKNieb3aXT6QyTjSlirmGcbVlGIR9OG8aGFgeBEFwVC0NgyapHBBDEMsYGRmOqFpHE6ZTrkBRFLKwp5kcBZNIQCxyDgGF9BMQp5BQNBLmQ6FEJ8%20xQEKAB02p0fBhATHeZpQFRRZtCW1rlv00HgcydYZjM853E2cItoeWyhoarJdoG2S9hcCIDkOS4jnSY4fIZRFQDyfJzgujbYKCEJQn%20sLwpYSJQKiOAoAqeLKhJH63JqVJAYiIF6WynI9mcJmQGZamLvQllPJxhDYiQZD9jcqUuQ8zyschNmAdujk0cAQkYRM5nYA6ooeTCko%20VlQVKiqxKkuSlLalFepHrpJ6ssam7cjO-KkTmEAiu5-ptYie7Cp1%20LLmqfVajqUoxaNcUmkIiRXqWNr5La%20RiQ%20LpSC%2076fl4P6%20sA-oAYkwbDWu2EjEpUHfbB9EIWQpV0HhWXEQpOHpEmKlmKm0OEVOWYzXKFF1A01G0YDxDoExiAsUh7GYNj3GhPxgnY6JaOhYWzTSdevQVpDP21lMsNOepXlaXtLJ7N2KnGflHNpcVVkI%20OtlEQ5s4NQeHQANZFAA7pwRLae2YbBGeZhbsciVC7LGUdaQeWmQVznDo8dIg9g5XJtLnDVbVRD1YViyfGrPOnvFKkOyRgr7p7n2a2eF7mvTp34BM52XY6QhAA)

Comment: Which is your primary question here?  Is it "why does a conditional type as return value require type assertions" as your title says and everything before your first horizontal rule asks? Or is it "why don't I need to convert to `unknown` first for this code vs this code" as asked in the rest of your question?  They are essentially separate questions with different answers; if you need both answered they should probably be split into separate question posts.  Which one is the topic here?

Comment: I've made the (hopefully correct) decision that your primary question is as the title and most of your post body asks.  For an answer to the second question about one-vs-two-step type assertions, you can look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60218424/2887218).