# what does chaining the "as" keyword in typescript do?

Tags: typescript

I stumbled upon this when searching for a workaround to set the return type of setTimeout.
Why can you give another type to unknown?

`setTimeout(...) as unknown as number`

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218840/2887218).  Not sure that this is exactly a duplicate, but the answer is essentially the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I cast or change the generic type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218424/how-can-i-cast-or-change-the-generic-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested chaining is used when you can't assert the type to the desired type directly. Since you can assert anything as `unknown` and assert `unknown` as anything else, you can assert the type as `unknown` first and then to the type that you are looking for.

Example:

```
const str: string = 'str'
const numStr = str as number; // expected error
const numStr2 = str as unknown as number; // no error
const unknwn: unknown = 'str';
const numStr3 = unknwn as number; // no error
```

I wouldn't recommend using this approach, since it's completely breaking type safety, but it can be used as a last resort